# Computing normals at each point in a point-cloud?

Tags: c++, math, normals, point-clouds

I have a series of points that form a point cloud.  I need to compute the normal vector at each point and cast a ray from that point in the direction of the normal vector.  What type of formula do I need to use to compute the normal vector in this situation?

EDIT*
I have a series of points (x, y, z) that form a point cloud (call this A), which forms the shape of a half sphere.  I also have another point cloud (call this B), which I fitted a surface to, that forms another half sphere which fits inside A.  I want to measure the length of how far these surfaces are far apart from each other, so my plan is to cast a ray from each point in A, to the surface B and measure the intersection to that point.  I hope this explanation makes my question more clear.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Interesting question, but we need more information (and code).

Answer (score 2):

I developed a [code](https://github.com/pedrogalher/Normals_Computation) in Python that will calculate the normal at each point of a point cloud. You could adapt it to C++.

-Basically you calculate the Single Value Decomposition from the k points near your points.

It will provide you with information regarding where the variance is bigger and smaller.

-Then you take the direction where the variance is smaller (eigenvector associated to the smallest eigenvalue). This eigenvector is the normal to the plane passing through your k-points (including your point P). Finally, repeat this to each of the points of the point cloud.

Comment: Hi Pedro, I am stuck in the same problem. Your above code link is not working. Can you please update the above link or paste the code here. It will be very helpful to me. Thanks.

Comment: Hi! I'm really glad you are interested in my solution. I had to macke a few changes on it and thats why i removed it. I'll upload again during the next weeks. I'll let you know when it is ready :)

Comment: Hi Pedro, Thanks for your reply. I am eagerly waiting for your solution to try on my problem statement.

Comment: Hi Sandeep, I have just updated the link to the code in my answer. There you find the calculation of normals for 2D and 3D. Even though I initially applied it to ellipses and ellipoides, it can be used for other shapes. Could you please update my answer if you find it useful? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a mesh so that you know which other local points a point is connected to?

In which case the normal at the point is the average (ie normalize to a unit vector of one) the cross product between each pair of lines meeting at the point.

Comment: should it be "each adjacent pair of lines"?

Comment: I could fit a surface to it, yes.

Comment: As an approximation one could take nearby points and consider "segments" joining these with each other and/or the point in question. Crossproduct of these segments could be averaged to get a normal. This will have issues near boundaries of the surface of course.

Comment: Shouldn't you take the unit vectors (i.e. length=1) for the cross products instead?

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you establish correspondence between the two meshes?  That is, for every point in mesh A, there a corresponding point in mesh B at a different location as a result from translation/scaling/rotation.  If so, then you can use [Procustes Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem) to find the optimal translation/scaling/rotation transformation matrices between the two clouds.  In the example provided in the OP, the scaling matrix can reveal the distances between the two meshes.
2. If the two meshes are arbitrary, then the best algorithm I can think of is to first put both point clouds in the same oct-tree.  From here, you can iterate through every point in mesh A and find the nearest point in mesh B.  The "minimum distance between two meshes" is the minimum distance found between 2 points after iterating.

The alternative to 2 is simply brute force iterate through all of the points:

```
double min=BIG_NUMBER;
for(Point a : meshA)
   for(Point b : meshB)
       if(dist(a,b)<min) min=dist(a,b);
```